# Text exceeds View on Iphone

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Check this snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{margin: 80}}>
        <View style={{ padding: 5, backgroundColor: 'honeydew', borderWidth: '1', borderColor: 'black'}}>
          <View style={{margin:5, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <View>
                  <Text style={{width:50}}>Test </Text>
              </View>

              <View style={{backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
                  <Text>this text exceeds the bordered view on iphone, should just wrap and fill the view</Text>
              </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The text with yellow background is rendered partially outside the view with the black border.

This can be tested here: https://snack.expo.io/HJRRjutuW

Why doesn't it render properly? And what should I change so it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `flexDirection: 'row'` from

```
<View style={{margin:5, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
```

also updated snack

https://snack.expo.io/rJ6N8tKdb

Or you can add `flexWrap`

```
<View style={{margin:5, flexDirection: 'row',flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
```

output will be like 
[image: this]

**EDIT**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{margin: 80}}>
        <View style={{ padding: 5, backgroundColor: 'honeydew', borderWidth: '1', borderColor: 'black'}}>
          <View style={{margin:5, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
              <View >
                  <Text style={{width:50}}>Test </Text>
              </View>

              <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
                  <Text>this text exceeds the bordered view on iphone, should just wrap and fill the view</Text>
              </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want the two text blocks next to eachother. Removing the flexDirection: 'row' will display them under eachother

Comment: updated my answer, now they will be displayed to each other, also saved changed to snack

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but in your second example, the first text does not have a fixed width anymore, while it should be 50...

Comment: updated that portion. now its static 50 width, once you change (eg. 30 or 40) , it will be adapted by right portion automatically

Comment: Although I don't really understand why, your last edit seems to solve the problem :) Thanks @Jigar Shah

Comment: Glad to help you, I have used flexWrap so it is stopping content to exceed view, another thing is assigned width to first text and flex:1 to second text so its working as expected

Answer (score 0):

If I measure the screenwidth and subtract the rest from it, it looks like I want it to, but this is not an elegant solution:

https://snack.expo.io/r1xCX5td-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Dimensions} from 'react-native';



export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
      let stretchWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width - 240;

    return (
      <View style={{margin: 80}}>
        <View style={{ padding: 5, backgroundColor: 'honeydew', borderWidth: '1', borderColor: 'black'}}>
          <View style={{margin:5, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <Text style={{width:50}}>Test</Text>
              </View>

              <View style={{width:stretchWidth,backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
                  <Text>this text exceeds the bordered view on iphone, should just wrap and fill the view</Text>
              </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```